# Alguien podria darme un ejemplo de numeros amigos en PHP

Tags: php

Ayuda con un ejemplo de verificacion de numeros amigos en PHP, No encuentro ningun ejemplo o tutorial en la web

Dos números enteros positivos A y B son números amigos si la suma de los divisores propios de A es igual a B y la suma de los divisores propios de B es igual a A.

Los divisores propios de un número incluyen la unidad pero no el propio número.

SOY NUEVO EN PHP E INTENTE MODIFICAR UN CODIGO QUE ENCONTRE DE JAVA:

```
if($_POST)
{   
    $num1 = $_POST
    ['numero1'];
    $num2 = $_POST
    ['numero2'];

    $suma = 0;

    for($i=1;$i<$num1;$i++){

             if($num1%$i==0){

            $suma=$suma+$i;
         }
    }

    if($suma==$num2){
       $suma=0;
       for($i=1;$i<$num2;$i++){  
            if($num2%$i==0){
               $suma=$suma+$i;
           }
       }

       if($suma==$num1){
          echo 'Son Amigos';
       }else{
                 echo 'No son Amigos';
       }
    }        
    else{
              echo 'No son Amigos';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: dale editar y añade que es eso de números amigos, pues muy seguro no a todos los usuarios les queda claro

Comment: Hola, puedes colocar lo que tienes desarrollado hasta ahora ya que no que entiendo lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude resolverlo :D

```
if($_POST)
{   
    $num1 = $_POST
    ['numero1'];
    $num2 = $_POST
    ['numero2'];         


            for($i = 1, $total1 = 0, $sum1 = 0; $i < $num1; $i++){
                if ($num1 % $i == 0){
                    $total1++;
                    $sum1=$sum1+$i;                 
                }                   
             }


            for($i = 1, $total2 = 0, $sum2 = 0; $i < $num2; $i++){
                if ($num2 % $i == 0){
                    $total2++;
                    $sum2=$sum2+$i;                 
                }                   
             }
            echo "La suma de divisores de $num1 es: ".$sum1." <br> La suma de divisores de $num2 es: ".$sum2;
    if ($num1 == $sum2 && $num2 == $sum1){
        echo " <br> Los Numeros son amigos!!!";
    }else{
        echo "<br> Los Numeros NO son amigos!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega una explicación, responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad